# Is there anything in French like saying “We” in place of you/I?

Tags: pronoms

In English it’s common to say “What are we having today?” in retail contexts instead of “What are *you* having today?”

And sometimes people might use “we” to mean “I” in a lighthearted, funny way to be relatable. For example, “So yeah, that’s how we’re doing right now,” to mean “Yeah, that’s how I’m doing.”

Could there be a way to say something like this in French? Are pronouns ever swapped like this in polite speech or lighthearted speech?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this exists too in French and that would be a case where the natural pronoun used would be ***on***.

***On*** has the ability to replace any personal pronoun in a sentence, here *nous/vous*:

> What are **we** having today?
>
> *Qu'est-ce qu'**on** prend/choisit aujourd'hui ?*

and here *je/vous*

> So yeah, that’s how **we**’re doing right now.
>
> *Ben oui, **on** est/va comme ça maintenant.*

In situations where this *on* tend to be avoided for not being formal enough, like in a school, a teacher might use *nous* when actually meaning *vous*:

> *Qu'est ce que **nous** allons découvrir aujourd'hui ?*

Comment: Les verbes en français dans ta réponse me semblent à côté du sens anglais : "What are we having" c'est l'expression d'un serveur qui prend commande, ça se traduit peut-être plutôt par "Qu'est-ce qu'on prend/choisit aujourd'hui ?" non ? Quant à la deuxième phrase, "how we're doing" c'est plutôt "comment on **va**" que "comment on **fait**".

Comment: L'usage du *nous* peut également être plus approprié que le *on* précisément pour feindre un discours exagérément formel sur un ton humoristique, et cela va alors dans le sens de l'usage décrit en anglais par l'OP. Ex: un enfant amène un cadeau à un adulte. L'adulte s'exclame en riant "mais mais mais qu'avons-nous là ?". Le "on" ne rendrait pas le ton humoristique.